# How send string content from Python script to PHP server

Tags: php, python, string, concatenation

i have a script python that create a variable containing a string message. I want to send the content of this variable to a PHP script located to my web server, reading content and print the variable content.

This is the python script:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib

message = 'hello world'
data=[('data:',message)]

url='http://www.mywebsite.com/myPHPscript.php'
req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
#req.add_header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
page=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
print(page)
```

And this the PHP script:

```
<?php
$info = $_POST["data"];
echo $info;
?>
```

When i run the Pyhton script i get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 10, in <module>
TypeError: can't concat bytes to tuple
```

where the `line 10` in my python script is this:

```
page=urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode('utf-8')
```

Thanks all for your help

Comment: You should try requests.py, it's way easier: page = requests.post(url,data={"data":"test data"}).text